# What is the probability that the distance from L to 0 is smaller than the distance from M to 0?

Tags: probability, self-study

> **Two points L and M belongs to the interval [0, 1] are chosen at**
>   **random. Thus, the interval is divided into 3 smaller sections.**
>
> **What is the probability that the distance from L to 0 is smaller than**
>   **the distance from M to 0?**

**My attempted solution.**

The condition stands if we have,

$0L < 0M$

$\Rightarrow M-L > 0$

$\Rightarrow M > L$

Since, the plotted line passes through the diagonal of the unit square, the area is $\frac{1}{2}$.

So, the probability is, $\frac{1/2}{1}=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

**Is this solution correct? Why or why not?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always apply a reasonability check to your answers.  That is, ask yourself:

> Is it reasonable that the probability is zero?

In your case, you are modeling throwing two darts at a line segment $[0, 1]$, and want to know the probability that the first dart is closer to zero than the second dart.  A probability of zero would mean that the situation is impossible, which it is clearly not!

The correct answer is $\frac{1}{2}$, which you can arrive at in multiple ways.  One simple way is to observe that the roles of $L$ and $M$ in the problem are interchangeable, you know *exactly* the same things about both.  Therefore the answer cannot depend on the labeling of one varaible as $L$ and the other as $M$, so the following probabilities must be equal

$$P(L > M) = P(M > L)$$

Since these probabilities must sum to $1$, it follows that they must both be $\frac{1}{2}$(*).

(*) I've snuck in a small assumption that $P(L = M) = 0$.  Do you see where?

Comment: I have rewritten my solution.

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to change the content of the question after you have asked it.  Better to leave the original, and then add in the correction as additional information.

Answer (score 0):

No the answer should be 1/2.  It is the probability that one uniform random variable is larger than another independent one.

Comment: Probably, I have a bug in. It should be $M-L>0$, rather than $M+L>0$.